# What is the person with whom you share the same interests?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a person with whom you share the same interests and hobbies?
Example

> I am looking for my ______ with whom I can watch movies for hours

Comment: That person is your PIC (partner in crime), assuming you actually do it together, not just both like doing it. Even though you're not actually committing crimes, it can still be used.

Comment: @Hank anything less criminal? I am using this for my website and tagline `Find your partners in crime` would sound a little bit bad.

Comment: A partner, a business partner, a creative partner, a friend.

Comment: I would totally click a link to "Find my PIC"

Comment: @Lambie first two are little bit formal and last one is a little bit banal.

Comment: @Hank I am calling police

Comment: @comPTON PIC has started carrying an informal "best friend" usage, referring to someone you do everything with and who you always want by your side. But I understand your usage may not fit it.

Comment: @Hank now the problem is not everybody in my website knows English that good to know that PIC is something good

Comment: Having a predisposition to *jump out of windows* is so unusual it's difficult to actually imagine a context where anyone might want to use the cited example (*John is my **fellow-weirdo***, perhaps? :). But for more credible contexts there are [many poptential terms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/compadre), which I think makes this a POB question with no single "correct" answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I updated my doltish question.Thus it will be easier for you to help your best friend(me)

Comment: Yeah, well, if not everybody "***in*** your website" doesn't know English ***that good***, it's best to keep it simple, and avoid words like banal. Partner is really the simplest term, in my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie but this is not my website

Comment: Never mind. You didn't get my point. The person is your friend. What other term is there?? Pal, friend, fellow couch potato.

Comment: @Hank you forgot  "that good"

Comment: @comPTON: It might now depend on whether John is unambiguously the only person having such a relationship with you (*He's **my soul-mate***, perhaps?) or one of potentially many *He's **a fellow-enthusiast***, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers John is somebody I don't know but I am looking for him

Comment: Additional to what @FumbleFingers suggested, **soul-mate** does not have to be relationship/dating-related. Just to make that known.

Comment: @Hank that is my website. This isn't. By `this` I am talking about English.stackexchange

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you'd do better referring to this hypothetical person as your ***alter-ego***, or even ***doppleganger***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as far as my narrow mind knows doppleganger is a person who is like you physically, am I erring?

Comment: @Hank thanks for the information. FumbleFingers soul-mate is the word I was looking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers now perhaps ye will post it as an answer thus future generations will also find an answer?

Comment: Well, yes. But unless you go for some more self-explanatory compound noun such as ***perfect companion***, I think you'll *have* to bend things a bit (I very much doubt there's a single word with exactly and only the meaning you seek). But Hank's *partner-in-crime* is very idiomatic, and would work perfectly well for native speakers. You're making the problem far more difficult by asking for something that's both idiomatic *and* likely to be easily understood by people with limited knowledge of idiomatic English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you have already told me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a person you are romantically with. Soul-mate would be a good word for this situation.

Comment: You are very right my grandiloquent pal, but somebody hath posted an answer before in the comments.That is very saddening indeed.But thanks for thy answer!

Comment: @Murad Answers are supposed to be posted as answers, not as comments. However, this answer lacks any references.

Answer (score 2):

Anne Shirley (originally of Green Gables) called these people *kindred spirits*, which I think would be fairly well-understood.

From [*Anne's House of Dreams*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A_BEAQAAMAAJ&dq=anne's%20house%20of%20dreams&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q=kindred%20spirits&f=false) (emphasis added):

> “. . . If a person sorter see
>   eye to eye with you, and has pretty much the same ideas about things,
>   and the same taste in jokes . . . .”
>
> “Oh, I understand,” exclaimed Anne, light breaking in upon her. “It’s
>   what I used to call—still call in quotation marks—‘**kindred spirits**.’”

(L.M. Montgomery, *Anne's House of Dreams*, 1917)

And, from an actual dictionary (Cambridge):

> [**kindred spirit**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/kindred-spirit) *noun*
>   a person who has the same opinions, feelings, and interests as you:
>   *We recognized each other as kindred spirits as soon as we met.*

It's a little old-fashioned and romantical, but I think would work in your context. It's also a little more flexible than *soul mate*, in the sense that you generally expect to have only one soul mate in the universe, whereas you can meet many kindred spirits and find all of them to be special and rewarding.